# Find the size of a single row in MySQL (MyISAM)

Tags: mysql, perl

I would like to know if it is possible to find the row size of a MySQL table.

The challenge is we have 704 columns in the row. I know MySQL supports 65,535 bytes (MyISAM).

Please help me with the query or Perl script to find it.

Comment: This kind of problem is sometimes symptomatic of poor design.

Comment: This just has to be a database design mistake.

Comment: This will depend on a number of things and if you even have one variable lenght column on a row, each row will potentially be a different size

Comment: We have no other option now. The database created 15 years back. Please anyone help me to figure out the solution.

Comment: `select length(col1) + length(col2) +  ...`

Comment: _The database created 15 years back_ Dont tell me the original designer is now the manager, right?

Comment: I am not sure who created it :)

Comment: If I had a nickel...

Comment: @ThisSuitIsBlackNot I was confident. Just confused that I could hammer it.

Comment: Why do you need to know this information? What are you going to do with the number once you have found it? Are you referring to to the maximum possible space occupied by all the fields in a record? Do you have any true varchar fields?